# Selecting Dropdown list in IE with VBA

Tags: html, excel, drop-down-menu, vba

I have been trying to select a drop down list in a web page using VBA, which I'm new to. In HTML the drop down menu is stated as **Button** and not **Select**. Here is the HTML code:

```
<span class='btn-group'>
  <button id='str_listing-btn' name='str_listing-btn' type='button' class='btn btn-default dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' data-value='For Sale'>
    For Sale
    <span class='caret' style='margin-left:5px;'>
    </span>
  </button>
  <ul class='dropdown-menu wptk_crud_dropdown' id='str_listing' data-value='str_listing' role='menu'>
    <li>
      <a href='#' data-value='For Sale'>For Sale</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href='#' data-value='For Rent'>For Rent</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href='#' data-value='Wanted To Buy'>Wanted To Buy</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href='#' data-value='Wanted To Rent'>Wanted To Rent</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</span>
```

I have tried a few VBA codes to select one of the options. Below is the latest code that I have used but after running it nothing seems to happen to the drop down menu:

```
Private Sub InsertPropwall_Click()

Dim objIE1 As Object
objIE1.navigate ("http://www.propwall.my/classifieds/post_ad?action=add")

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until objIE1.ReadyState = 4

objIE1.Document.getElementById("str_listing-btn").Value = "For Rent"

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until objIE1.ReadyState = 4

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dropdown isn't a dropdown (as you've mentioned). Instead, it's an unordered list with a number of links as clickable options. With that said, the `For Rent` option isn't contained in `str_listing-btn`. Notice how that tag closes before any of the options are available. Instead, it's contained in the list below it.

Since I couldn't get into your link without creating an account, I tested out code to select the `For Rent` option on the main page. Take a look at my code, test it to see if it does what you need, then try to accommodate it into your code. Let us know if you need additional help.

```
Sub NavigateIt()
    Dim oIE As Object

    Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    oIE.navigate ("http://www.propwall.my/classifieds")
    oIE.Visible = True

    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until oIE.ReadyState = 4

    Set AvailableLinks = oIE.document.getelementbyid("list-listing").getelementsbytagname("a")

    For Each cLink In AvailableLinks
        If cLink.innerhtml = "For Rent" Then
            cLink.Click
        End If
    Next cLink

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi user3561813, your solution works! Thanks! Gosh it would be easier if it was <select> in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

**CSS selector:**

You could have used a CSS selector e.g.

```
a[data-value=For Sale] or a[data-value=For Rent]
```

This says first element with `a` tag that has attribute `data-value` whose value is `'For Sale'`; Or, `'For Rent'` in the subsequent example.

---

**CSS query:**

[image: CSS query]

---

**VBA:**

You apply the CSS selector using the querySelector method of document

```
objIE1.Document.querySelector("a[data-value=For Sale]").Click
```