# select from a webpage list using vba

Tags: html, excel, vba

I'm trying to automate input to a webpage by selecting from a list then hitting a submit button. I will need to do this for several hundred data, repetitively. I got the part opening IE and getting to the webpage (intranet) but having trouble selecting from a list. Below is the snippet of the webpage list.

```
<ul class="PickGradientType">
  <li class="PickGradientType-tab_uWGMp">HIGH</li>
  <li class="PickGradientType-tab_uWGMp OrderForm_active_Di-9p">MEDIUM</li>
  <li class="PickGradientType-tab_uWGMp">LOW</li>
</ul>
```

Here is the closest code I found that can help me but since the webpage has no "id" or "tagname", how can the existing code be modified to select any one of the 3 options (HIGH, MEDIUM, or LOW).

```
Set AvailableLinks = oIE.document.getelementbyid("list-listing").getelementsbytagname("a")

For Each cLink In AvailableLinks
    If cLink.innerhtml = "For Rent" Then
        cLink.Click
    End If
Next cLink
```

The above code came from this link:
[Selecting Dropdown list in IE with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32221907/selecting-dropdown-list-in-ie-with-vba)

Thanks in advance for helping out a newbie.

EDIT: Thanks to @Doomenik, here's the updated solution:

```
Set AvailableLinks = oIE.getElementsByClassName("PickGradientType")

For Each cLink In AvailableLinks
    If cLink.innerhtml = "MEDIUM" Then
        cLink.Click
    End If
Next cLink
```

Comment: `oIE.document.getElementsByClassName("PickGradientType").getelementsbytagname("li")` Would select the right one, the for each inner code should be modified by what you want to achieve

Comment: thanks @Doomenik I made a slight tweak but your instruction led me to the answer.

Comment: Glad it helped !